# No video sound on Ubuntu from laptop computer speaker

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, audio

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 along Windows7 on my laptop.

I can listen to spotify and no problem.

But any kind of video on Firefox or Chrome does not play sound.

It plays video but without sound.

When I play avi, there is no sound coming from my laptop computer speaker either.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

I am using Dell Latitude D830.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the default sound output used by the system is the same as for Spotify?

It might be the origin of your problem.

If not, does changing the volume has any effect in Spotify? (when you move the volume slider in the system taskbar)?

By the way, it should be useful if you told us which desktop environment your are using. :)

Comment: How do I know which sound output used by spotify?